# Getting count of overlapping portion of different line features within one shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have a line shapefile that has overlapping on certain portion of the line features. I need to know the count of where these overlapping occurs and if there is no overlap to keep it as Null or 0 as it still a count of 1 line that passes through the route. 
I have a point shapefile of where these lines start and end.

Eg. A line runs from 1>2 another lines run from 1>3 and one from 1>5.  A line runs from 2>3 and another line from 3>4.
In the portion of the red box I know there should be overlapping as the lines that feed 1>2, 1>3 and 1>5 have the same route (geographic location as well).   Portions 2>3 and 3>4 of the line has no overlap.

I am trying to figure out a workflow and I am using QGIS 2.18. Any ideas?

[image: Visual Summary of what I need to achieve :)]

Comment: Just to be pedantic, I believe there should be a 2 between 2 & 3 (a line runs from 1>3, and another from 2>3).

Comment: You are right @phloem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can (1) break these lines into segments, (2) count overlapping segments, and (3) keep only one feature at each location (while removing others) just for labeling.

---

(1) **Explode lines** (`Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector geometry tools`) to break polylines into segments.

(2) Open the attribute table of the above `exploded` layer. Start the Field Calculator and create a new integer field with an expression `count("id", group_by:=geom_to_wkt($geometry))` ... if you have `id` field.

(3) Remove duplicated segments by **Delete duplicate geometries** (`Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector general tools`).
 This will ensure not to show multiple labels at each segment.

Comment: I have tried workflow suggested but it gives me wrong counts.

Comment: @geogeek-pkav That's too bad. Umm...perhaps your lines are not topologically aligned each other?

Comment: @kashuito can you help me with the following: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295613/start-and-end-point-of-line-segments-line-shapefile-and-getting-specific-label

Comment: Hi @geogeek-pkav Yes I will try to look into the question.

Comment: @geogeek-pkav I made a couple of tests on your other question, but could not find a viable solution. Sorry.