# Start and end point of line segments (line shapefile) and getting specific labels from a point shapefile

Tags: qgis

I have a line shapefile where I need to break the line at the specific intersection with points using QGIS 2.18.20. I refer to these segments as ‘tray sections’.

Now I need to have two fields: f_from and f_to in the ‘tray sections’. In these fields, I need to calculate the specific label from the point layer ie a specific ID number.  I also need to have x and y fields for the f_from and x and y for the f_to as well.

Eg. See screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Are your points topologically related with your lines? As in, do your point features sit perfectly within the same space as your line features?

Comment: Some do, and some do not @RobinHorner

Answer (score 1):

**QGIS 2.18.20** ... **! partial answer !**

This is probably not an answer you have anticipated, but anyway...

- This is a `Virtual Layer` approach, you may / may not be familiar with.
- As of today, latest QGIS versions (both 3.2.3 and 2.18.24) have some unknown problems with the Virtual Layer. You would have to stick with your `QGIS 2.18.20`.

A virtual layer syntax is:

```
SELECT nodes.id AS f_from_to, 
       st_x(nodes.geometry) AS x, 
       st_y(nodes.geometry) AS y, 
       line.* 
FROM nodes
CROSS JOIN line
ON st_intersects(st_buffer(nodes.geometry, 10), 
                 st_geometryn(line.geometry, 1))
```

[image]

Another caveat:

- This syntax does not distinguish `f_from` and `f_to` (you will notice I have `f_from_to` field, which is mixture of two). Hopefully SQL experts help us to fix it).

So sorry for this premature one, hopefully for your for for thought.

Comment: Hi @Kazuhiot, thanks. Can I get your email to send the workflow I have so far? A bit to long to add in the comment section.

Comment: @geogeek-pkav Is it possible for you to edit your question and add your workflow? You will see some questions at this site, especially complex ones, have been edited/updated as going toward solutions. Thanks!